# Spring Discovery First Bootstrap doesn't find ConfigServer

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-config

Currently I am running Spring Boot Services with Discovery First. 
Starting the services one after another works just fine, but I am having issues starting the services all at once via docker-compose.

The discovery first bootstrap seems to not work as I expected. I would assume that the service would halt / retry till he receives the configuration from the configuration service, which has been discovered via eureka. But currently it will try to resolve the configuration once and then the service will start immediately after - no matter if a configuration has been brought or not.

The service bootstrap looks as following:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: my-service
  cloud:
    config:
      fail-fast: false
      discovery:
        enabled: true
        service-id: configserver
      retry:
        initialInterval: 2000
        multiplier: 1.5
        maxInterval: 60000
        maxAttempts: 10

server:
  port: ${APPLICATION_PORT:16000}
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${EUREKA_HOSTNAME:localhost}:15000/eureka/
```

The eureka config looks as following:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: manager
server:
  port: 15000
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${EUREKA_HOSTNAME:localhost}:15000/eureka/
```

Last but not least - the configserver config looks as following:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: configserver
  cloud:
    config:
      fail-fast: true
server:
  port: 15001
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${EUREKA_HOSTNAME:localhost}:15000/eureka/
```

Anyone able to give any advice here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue:

Actually I found two issues on our side. The first one is not having a suitable lease renewal interval. The client just retried receiving the configuration with the cached services. 
Since the cached services did not contain a configuration service, he wasn't able to receive a proper configuration.

The second problem was to not wait for enough time. This has been fixed in raising the maxAttempts higher. So the config and discovery services do have enough time to come up.

The client Configuration looks like the following now:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: service
  cloud:
    config:
      fail-fast: true
      discovery:
        enabled: true
        service-id: CONFIGSERVER
      retry:
        initialInterval: 2000
        multiplier: 1.5
        maxInterval: 60000
        maxAttempts: 100

server:
  port: ${APPLICATION_PORT:16000}
eureka:
  instance:
    lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds: 10
  client:
    fetch-registry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${EUREKA_HOSTNAME:localhost}:15000/eureka/
```

Comment: This is old Spring configuration. spring.cloud.config.discovery doesn't work in current version. Current property is spring.config.import